# Unexpected paint order in for loop

Tags: java, swing, loops

Could anyone help me figure out why my circle is not printing out on top of the square all the way to the top? The square seems to print out onto the frame perfectly fine but I've been unable to figure out why the loop stops after the 2nd row but never completing up to the 6th row. thank guys!

This is my main `ExampleGUI.java` class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExampleGUI {
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example Graphics");
        ExamplePanel panel = new ExamplePanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This is my method/constructor class `ExamplePanel.java`

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExamplePanel extends JPanel {

    public ExamplePanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        int x = 0;
        int x2 = 5;
        int y = 500;
        int y2 = 505;
        int w = 100;
        int w2 = 90;
        int h = 100;
        int h2 = 90;
        int i, j;

        for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            x = 0;
            x2 = x + 5;
            System.out.println(x + " " + y);
            for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);

                x = x + w;
                x2 = x2 + w2 + 10;


            }

            x = x + w;
            y2 = 505;

            y = y - h;
            y2 = (y2 - h2) - 10;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `j ++` shouldn't be `j++`????

Comment: `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);`? Don't use magic numbers when there are constants available

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove your  `y2= 505;`
You have mistakenly set your y2 to the same value each iteration :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Now I see I was resetting the y2 value. Thanks :)

Comment: np :) read your code carefully most times the errors are because of human error